# How to read rows of csv file into numpy array or list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have CSV file which contains only float values. [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncKkyS_WeJrd7EnbaI3QXsqAEX_OQoKQ/view?usp=sharing)
I want to read each row of CSV file as a numpy array or list in list( which so ever is fast) but not in pandas.

The rows in CSV files are non-uniform and that's why i am getting error like

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #4 (got 1000 columns instead of 10000)
Line #5 (got 1000 columns instead of 10000)
Line #6 (got 1000 columns instead of 10000)
Line #7 (got 5000 columns instead of 10000)
```

When i am trying code :

```
np.genfromtxt('hctsa_timeseries-data.csv',delimiter=',')
```

The desired output should be something like:

[[row1],[row2],[row3].....]

Comment: Read a row, split on delimiter, and make an array from the list.  Specify dtype if necessary.

Comment: could you please provide me some code hints

Comment: I talking about basic Python and numpy methods.

Answer (score 0):

I run the two following methods numpy.genfromtxt() and list, both of them seems fine. Not sure what's wrong with your code. But you can try the following:

Method 1 List:

```
import csv

row_list =[]
with open('/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/timeseries.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader: 
        row_list.append(row)
f.close()
```

Method 2 Numpy:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

with open('/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/timeseries.csv', 'r') as f:
    my_data = genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',')
f.close()
```

Comment: method 1 works but still not able go to create numpy